# Java Logarithm Clock Gives Innacurate Answers

Tags: java, swing, time, jlabel, clock

Ok, so I was building a clock that would give out times in the form of Log<sub>10</sub>(hour) and also minute and second in the same format, but I keep getting strange outputs when this runs. I get mostly NANs and sometimes infinity(or its negative). I have a feeling that something is wrong with the numbers that I am using(like maybe they are too large or something like that) NOTE: currentTime is a long, calendar is a Calendar, and hour, minute, and second are doubles. Also the clock variable is a JLabel. After the program goes through two iterations it always switches over to NANs.

```
this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        calendar.setTime(new Date(currentTime));
                        hour = Math.log10(hour);
                        minute = Math.log10(minute);
                        second = Math.log10(second);
                        System.out.println(hour + " " + minute + " " + second);
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void done() {

                        clock.setText("<html><body><p>Log Time: "
                                + "Log<sub>10</sub>(" + hour + ") || "
                                + "Log<sub>10</sub>(" + minute + ") || "
                                + "Log<sub>10</sub>(" + second + ")</p></body></html>");
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        }, 0, 200);
```

[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]

Comment: Why have you posted hard-to-read dark-blue-on-black screenshots, instead of just including the text in your post? What diagnosis have you performed to check the values of `hour`, `minute` and `second` *before* for log operations?

Comment: I used the debugger to put a breakpoint at the time when they are assigned values, and they seem to always be falling down in value.

Comment: Well yes, they would because you're taking the log of the previous value, which was the log of the value before that, etc - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't make a lot of sense:

```
currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
calendar.setTime(new Date(currentTime));
hour = Math.log10(hour);
minute = Math.log10(minute);
second = Math.log10(second);
```

You're setting the time in `calendar` - but then completely ignoring it. I would expect you'd want something like:

```
currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
calendar.setTime(new Date(currentTime));
hour = Math.log10(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
minute = Math.log10(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
second = Math.log10(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

EDIT: As noted on comments, you also need to consider what you'll do when the hour, minute or second is 0. (It's very unclear why you'd *want* to use a log-based clock to start with, to be honest.)

Comment: And still there would be a problem with the logarithms when the fields are 0.